# Bash consecutive and parallel loops/commands

Tags: bash, scripting, parallelism

I want to run some simulations using a Python tool that I had made. The catch is that I would have to call it multiple times with different parameters/arguments and everything.

For now, I am using multiple `for` loops for the task, like:

```
for simSeed in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    for launchPower in 17.76 20.01 21.510 23.76
    do
        python sim -a $simSeed -p $launchPower
    done
done
```

In order for the simulations to run simultaneously, I append a `&` at the end of the line where I call the simulator.

```
python sim -a $simSeed -p $launchPower &
```

Using this method I am able to run multiple such seeds. However, since my computer has limited memory, I want to re-write the above script so that it launches the inner `for` loop parallelly and the outer `for` loop sequentially.

As an example, for `simSeed = 1`, I want 5 different processes to run with `launchPower` equal to `17.76 20.01 21.510 23.76`. As soon as this part is complete, I want the script to run for `simSeed = 2` and again 5 different parallel processes with `launchPower` equal to `17.76 20.01 21.510 23.76`.

How can I achieve this task?

TLDR:

I want the outer loop to run sequentially and inner loop to run parallelly such that when the last parallel process of the inner loop finishes, the outer loop moves to the next iteration.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This looks like a job for GNU parallel.

Comment: How can I achieve this task using `parallel`? Isn't it similar to using the `&` command? (I don't have much XP in using `parallel`)

Comment: add `wait` between `done` and `done`

Comment: Why would `launchPower` be `1,2,3,4,5` ? Your loop is using 17.76 20.01 21.510 23.76 instead. Where does the 1,2,3,4,5 come from?

Comment: @terdon ach... I mixed up the values... you are correct... Lemme fix the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU parallel has several options to limit resource usage when starting jobs in parallel.

The basic usage for two nested loops would be

```
parallel python sim -a {1} -p {2} ::: 1 2 3 4 5 ::: 17.76 20.01 21.510 23.76
```

If you want to launch at most 5 jobs at the same time, e.g., you could say

```
parallel -j5 python <etc.>
```

Alternatively, you can use the `--memfree` option to start new jobs only when enough memory is free, e.g. at least 256 MByte

```
parallel --memfree 256M python <etc.>
```

Note that the last option will kill the most recently started job if the memory falls below 50% of the "reserve" value stated (but it will be re-qeued for catch-up automatically).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for...

If I have multiple such jobs (queued one after the other) then using the `-j` option it sequentially executes the first `j` jobs, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Once the first of these `j` jobs has finished, it will start the first of the "remaining" jobs in the loop order, (i.e. Job `j+1`) and so on.

Comment: That said, note that `parellel` only guarantees the order in which jobs are _started_, not necessarily the order in which they are completed. For example with `-j5`, if job 2 takes 300s and job 3 only 20s, job 6 will be started before job 2 is complete. If job 6 also only takes 20s, its results will be "on disk" before those of job 2, which can lead to confusion. Although, now that I think about it ... it should be obvious, right ;)?

Comment: One quick and hopefully last question. I want to run this on a server (using ssh) so how do I get the console back after executing with parallel? ctrl+z doesn't work, for some reason (it terminates the whole thing)

Comment: @MaJoR21 just send it to the background: `parallel -j5 python <etc.> &`

Comment: Yep. Just did that. Also used `nohup` because I was worried if the HUP signal would not terminate the process. Thanks @terdon :D

Comment: @MaJoR21 sounds like you really want to look into GNU [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or `tmux` as well.

Comment: Ohh.. I know about screen/tmux. However, I don't know how it will fit into this scenario? Tmux basically divides the whole term window to multiple terminals so that one can access multiple terminals simultaneously, right? I OTOH, just have to ssh to my server, run the `parallel` script and logout so that it keeps running on the server and I can do something else on my system

Comment: @MaJoR21 I moved this to a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105507/discussion-on-answer-by-adminbee-bash-consecutive-and-parallel-loops-commands) so we don't spam the comments.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments this is exactly what GNU `parallel` is for:

```
for simSeed in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    ## Launch 5 instances in parallel 
    parallel -j5 python sim -a $simSeed -p {} ::: 17.76 20.01 21.510 23.76
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the respective process IDs and `wait` for them to finish:

```
for simSeed in {1..5}; do
  pids=()
  for launchPower in 17.76 20.01 21.510 23.76; do
    python sim -a $simSeed -p $launchPower &
    pids+=($!)
  done
  wait ${pids[@]}
done
```

`pids` is an array of process IDs of the background jobs of the inner loop.
With the `${pids[@]}` all elements of the array are passed to the wait command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Since your solution is quite similar to my current setup, I will try this first... However, `parallel` does seem easy to use.

Comment: Note that you don't actually need to save the PIDs, `wait` will wait for any child processes by default. So all you need is `for simSeed in {1..5}; do for launchPower in ...; do ...; done; wait; done;`